# What's the smallest rotation a brush-less motor can perform?

Tags: motor, brushless-motor

For example, I have a brush-less outrunner with 14 poles and 12 stator windings. It has three connectors. Can this motor be controlled in a way that it performs a single step of 30 degrees (360/12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any stepper motor can be microstepped. If you microstep, you can theoretically go as crazy as you want, but as you increase the number of microsteps, although you increase your resolution, you decrease the accuracy of the step.

http://www.linengineering.com/contents/stepmotors/pdf/Product_Guides/Lin_RG_StepMotorBasics.pdf

http://www.micromo.com/microstepping-myths-and-realities

Edit:

In regards to the original question, the smallest angle you can rotate is 8.57 degrees with a 14 pole 12 stator configuration. You can find a detailed explanation of this system here: http://www.aerodesign.de/peter/2001/LRK350/index_eng.html by clicking on the link for "Why does the Torquemax rotate so slowly and so forcefully" and scrolling down.

Comment: A brushless motor is not a stepper motor.

Comment: A brushless motor is not always a stepper motor, but a stepper motor is always a brushless motor. That being said, I originally thought he was talking about a stepper motor because he referenced step angle in his question. I've never used an outrunner, so maybe I'm wrong...I'll try to investigate.

Comment: That's true if you don't consider the electronics shipped with the motor and the goals a BLDC motor is designed to achieve wrt a stepper.

Comment: @Ugo I looked into what you're saying and I believe I now understand your point. I think this page details what you were saying: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79498/difference-between-brushless-motor-and-stepper-motor. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Yep, right to the point :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I was indeed talking about non-stepper motors.

Comment: @AndrewCapodieci I'm not sure why you changed your mind on your original answer.  Any brushless motor can indeed be microstepped just like a stepper motor.  Stepper motors are built to have very small "full" steps and will have a different configuration but the principles still apply.  The open loop performance for both also depends on the load, friction and variation from the spec.  In closed loop brushless and steppers can be controlled to extremely fine angular positioning (pretty much as fine as your feedback).